Server sent event not sending events asynchronously - Spring MVC
I am working on building an API that utilizes the SSE in Spring MVC to stream data. I tried building the SSE using Spring WebFlux and I was able to get it to work and stream data asynchronously. But when I try to use SseEmitter in Spring MVC, I am unable to stream data.
The data is sent at the end of the last event all at once defeating the point of the SSE API. I have tried using a simple SSE API using the samples given online and I'm unable to get them to work.
 @GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public SseEmitter testSSe(){
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int iInLoop = i;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(iInLoop * 1000);
                emitter.send(iInLoop );
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        emitter.complete();
        return emitter;
    }


All of the events are emitted at the same time. How do I get the SSE to send the events instantly once they are sent by the emitter?

The requesting thread or the main thread shouldn't be blocked. It has to be able to return the emitter first to be able to send the events.
So the events should be sent from another thread while the main (request) thread should be allowed to complete returning the emitter.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
